# The prediction output repeats infinitely

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/input_fn/) for generating input functions on tensorflow.org.

Everything works fine until I try to print the predictions (it should be just 6 predictions).

```
y = regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(prediction_set))
print ("Predictions: {}".format(str(y)))
```

I get this output: `<generator object _as_iterable at 0x7fa66ec6cfa0>`.

If I try to convert the generator to a list with `list(y)`. The program freezes.

If I try to get only the first 30 items (even if there should be only 6):

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.islice(y, 30)))
```

I get the following:

```
[34.382435, 20.170452, 23.214834, 37.211243, 17.090082, 19.648254,
34.382435, 20.170452, 23.214834, 37.211243, 17.090082, 19.648254,
34.382435, 20.170452, 23.214834, 37.211243, 17.090082, 19.648254,
34.382435, 20.170452, 23.214834, 37.211243, 17.090082, 19.648254,
34.382435, 20.170452, 23.214834, 37.211243, 17.090082, 19.648254]
```

As you can see it's repeating values ad infinitum.

Am I missing something?

Tensorflow version: 0.12.0-rc1

Python version: 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

We recently revised the "Building Input Functions with tf.contrib.learn" tutorial to be up to date with the latest default behavior of predict() in Estimators, which returns a generator. The revised tutorial text is here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/input_fn/

And the latest code is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/input_fn/boston.py

Here's the relevant section, which uses itertools.islice, as in your last attempt:

```
y = regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(prediction_set))
# .predict() returns an iterator; convert to a list and print predictions                                                      
predictions = list(itertools.islice(y, 6))
print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))
```

I'm not seeing the behavior where the prediction values repeat when the second argument to islice is increased to 30. Could you try pulling the latest code from GitHub at the link above and let me know if you still encounter that?

Comment: Downloaded the code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/input_fn/boston.py) and I still get the same result if I increase the argument to islice.

With 10: `[33.596405, 18.607161, 21.850567, 33.849072, 16.530201, 18.338963, 33.596405, 18.607161, 21.850567, 33.849072]`